# Need example of conditional operator yielding an lvalue using conversion

Tags: c++

Chapter 4.7 of the book C++ Primer says:

> That result of the conditional operator is an lvalue if both expressions are lvalues or if they convert to a common lvalue type. Otherwise the result is an rvalue.

Can someone give me an example of a case where the operator yields an lvalue using a conversion to a common lvalue type?

Comment: _"...The type and value category of the conditional expression E1 ? E2 : E3 are determined according to the following rules:"_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
#include <type_traits>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct A {} a;
    struct B : A {} b;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<A &, decltype(argc > 0 ? a : b)>);
}
```